# How do I run code before task execution when using a shared_task in Celery

Tags: python, celery

I have a requirement that all my Celery tasks must be called with a specific keyword argument. I want to check and use the value of the keyword before my task is executed.
For instance, suppose I have the following:

```
@shared_task
def my_task(*args, **kwargs):
    foo = kwargs.get('bar')  # -> I don't want to copy this to all my tasks
    # Do stuff here
```

How can I create a new decorator called `my_special_shared_task` so that the below is equivalent to the above:

```
@my_special_shared_task
def my_task(*args, **kwargs):
    # Do stuff here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about task inheritance?
something like:

```py
class BaseTask(celery.Task):
    foo = "some_value"


@app.task(base=BaseTask)
def my_task(*args, **kwargs):
    # Do stuff here
    print(self.foo)
```

[here](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html#task-inheritance) is the documentation.

Comment: I actually tried that, but it then didn't store the result that the task returned. Any idea why that would be the case?

Comment: Sorry ignore that comment, looks like I was doing something else wrong